# Estimating molecular sizes using surface tension and heat of vaporization

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, biophysics, surface-tension

I'm confused about some wording (and how some of these concepts fit together) in this problem.

[image: Nelson, 1.6]

(It's from Nelson's *Biological Physics*.)

I'm not sure what "N molecules per centimeter in each of the three directions" means.

For part a, I think I have to find Σ in terms of ε ($J$)/Surface Area ($m^2$) and then divide $Q_{vap}$ by Σ to obtain some value with unit $m^{-1}$. (Is this right?)
But the value of Σ depends on the number and arrangement of molecules. What should I assume for the length, width, and height of the lattice?

I hope that if I can understand part a I'l be able to get b and c, but right now I'm not sure how to approach them.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure what "N molecules per centimeter in each of the three directions" means.

Your lattice is cubic. If you divide one centimeter per the size of the edge of one cube, you should find $N$ molecules.

> For part a, I think I have to find Σ in terms of ε (J)/Surface Area (m2) and then divide Qvap by Σ to obtain some value with unit m−1.

This is a good method.

> But the value of Σ depends on the number and arrangement of molecules. What should I assume for the length, width, and height of the lattice?

You know that the lattice is cubic, which is all the information you need.